# Coinbase trouble| Error 401 AuthenticationError

Tags: python, coinbase-api

```
from coinbase.wallet.client import Client

api_key = ""
api_secret = ""
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
print(client.get_accounts())
```

The simple example, but I get

`coinbase.wallet.error.AuthenticationError: APIError(id=authentication_error): request timestamp expired`

Comment: Maybe api_key / api_secret have expired?

Comment: By the way, api key and secret are inserted in the code

Comment: I have created today, and try to create again when it doesn't work.

Comment: looks like the library you are using has been deprecated https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-python

Comment: Is there analogs that i can use?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the server timezone to coinbase.com timeZone it is comparing the time from our server and coinbase server so try to put -08:00 timeZone . For me it is working if I do these changes.

if not you can run this script
https://gist.github.com/siddieswar/0adefee80292ae8e3055fdfdddab4180